# How to best connect this microwave to the exhaust vent?

Tags: vent, microwave-oven

I'm trying to connect my microwave to the existing exhaust vent.  The problem is that the microwave is about 1 inch to the left of the actual vent.  This is the part that I'm struggling with.  I have the following two options:

1 - Buy and install a boxy connector so that the two pieces are connecting just fine.

2 - Buy some metal tape and then proceed with cover the entire thing with that.

What course of action would you recommend?  I'm not too happy with either one of my options.

[image: microwave to existing vent connection]

Comment: Is that vent already used for a range hood, or is the photo showing the vent connected to the old microwave?

Comment: The vent is connected to the microwave that I put in.  I resolved this problem by buying a vent that has a flexible middle and one that fit snuggly at the top and the bottom (lowes has them.)